# Magento 2 - I get logged out from backend/admin if I change a setting

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, backend, session, amasty

I am getting logged out from the backend if I am changing a setting in a amasty extension.

How can I debug it to find it out what is causing it?

Comment: Check logs and check action files of plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled one extension after another and tried again after each step. I figured out that these two extension are causing the bug:

- MSP_Common
- MSP_DevTools